# Clashing EventListeners (?) Javascript DrawPad Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am making a small draw pad script using HTML5 canvas and JS.

I encountered a problem which I think maybe be caused by using 2 'mouseup' event listeners but I am not certain - so I was wondering if someone could take a look at the code.

The problem is that when dragging the brush size slider, if not letting go of the mouse while still hovering over the slider - the first line you try to draw on the canvas gets stopped half way.

**Actual link:** www.ronjrtech.com/draw

**Pastebin:** http://pastebin.com/hCbPkSRF

I do know the code itself is kind of a mess..

If there is anything else I could explain, please let me know!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That's a pretty huge wall of code, maybe do some more debugging work and nail it down to a smaller area of code and post your findings if you still can't figure it out. :)

Comment: I suspect is it something to with the event listener functions for the slider. I know its not too much help but it didn't do that before I added the slider :)